# Feature selection using statistical model

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-extraction, feature-selection

**Problem statement** **:**

I am working on a problem where i have to predict if customer will opt for loan or not.I have converted all available data types (object,int) into integer and now my data looks like below.

[image: view of data]

The highlighted column is my **Target** column where

**0** means **Yes**

**1** means **No**

There are **47 independent** column in this data set.

I want to do  **feature selection** on these columns against my **Target** column!!

I started with **Z-test**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import scipy.special as sp


def feature_selection_pvalue(df,col_name,samp_size=1000):
    relation_columns=[]
    no_relation_columns=[]
    H0='There is no relation between target column and independent column'
    H1='There is a relation between target column and independent column'
    sample_data[col_name]=df[col_name].sample(samp_size)
    samp_mean=sample_data[col_name].mean()
    pop_mean=df[col_name].mean()
    pop_std=df[col_name].std()
    print (pop_mean)
    print (pop_std)
    print (samp_mean)
    n=samp_size
    q=.5
    #lets calculate z
    #z = (samp_mean - pop_mean) / np.sqrt(pop_std*pop_std/n)
    z = (samp_mean - pop_mean) / np.sqrt(pop_std*pop_std / n)
    print (z)
    pval = 2 * (1 - st.norm.cdf(z))
    print ('p values is==='+str(pval))
    if pval< .05 :
        print ('Null hypothesis is Accepted for col ---- >'+H0+col_name)

        no_relation_columns.append(col_name)
    else:
        print ('Alternate Hypothesis is accepted -->'+H1)
        relation_columns.append(col_name)
        print ('length of list ==='+str(len(relation_columns)))


    return relation_columns,no_relation_columns
```

When i run this function , i always gets different results

```
for items in df.columns:
    relation,no_relation=feature_selection_pvalue(df,items,5000)
```

**My question is**

1. is above z-Test a reliable mean to do feature selection, when result differs each time
2. What would be a better approach in this case to do feature selection, if possible provide an example

Answer (score 0):

> What would be a better approach in this case to do feature selection,
>   if possible provide an example

Are you able to use `scikit` ? They are offering a lot of examples and possibilites to selection your features:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

If we look at the first one (Variance threshold):

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
X = df[['age', 'balance',...]] #select your columns
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
X_red = sel.fit_transform(X)
```

this will only keep the columns which have some variance and not have only the same value in it for example.